# 302 код ответа на GET запрос

Tags: http

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот делаю простой GET запрос:

```
GET /government.ru HTTP/1.1
Host: government.ru
Connection: keep-alive
```

Сервер отвечает:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /KYjQZ/government.ru
```

или так:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /KeNiZ/government.ru
```

или так:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /ReWSZ/government.ru
```

Подскажите:

1)GПравильно ли я понимаю, что временный адрес указанный в Location нужно использовать в заголовке Host ?

2)Зачем сервер выдает разные значения Location ?

3)И зачем сервер закрывает соединение, если же сам мне пишет, что нужно сделать новый запрос ? Это же не логично.

Comment: 1 нет. 2, 3 так захотел сервер

Comment: @Alexey Ten, подскажите, а в какой части моего запроса тогда нужно использовать Location ?

Comment: В `GET` ........

Comment: 3. сервер вам сказал, что вы обратились по адресу, но нужно перейти на другой url. Сервер сказал всё что хотел, зачем держать открытым соединение? Запрос же нужно делать клиенту, а не серверу

Comment: @ArchDemon, просто затем серверу тратить дополнительное время на повторное установление соединения, на  аутентификацию, если намерение клиента явное - получить запрашиваемую страницу.

Comment: Ну так клиент получил запрашиваемую страницу, а дальше клиент решает что ему делать. Может, после получения кода 302 клиент ничего не будет делать. К тому же наверняка есть причины, связанные с работой поисковых роботов

Comment: @ArchDemon, я понимаю, что это уже занудство с моей стороны :)  Но по факту клиент запрашиваемую страницу, как раз не получил, а получил только http-заголовки.

Comment: Клиент запрашивает не страницу, а ответ от сервера. И получает ответ без тела. Вполне нормальная ситуация. Вас это может удивить, но метод HEAD, например, тоже не содержит тела. Если провести аналогии, то 302 говорит вам о том, что вы обратились в нужную организацию, но обратились не к тому специалисту.